# passing directive attribute value to any controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a number of elements with a directive called scrollOffset eg

```
<section id="section1" scrollOffset="100">
...
</section>

<section id="section2" scrollOffset="100">
...
</section>
```

For the sake of understanding, I would like to be able to access the value of the scrollOffset attribute from within any container belonging to any module in my app, if I know the element id.

My first problem is how to declare the directive properly as I've seen numerous ways of doing it eg

```
var myScroller = angular.module('scrollOffset', []);

myScroller.directive('scrollOffset', function ( $rootScope ) {

    return function (scope, element, attr) {
        var offset = scope.$eval(attr.scrollOffset);
    }   
});
```

I declare a separate module containing various controllers.  I would like to be able to access the scrollOffset attribute in these controllers

```
var myControllers = angular.module ( 'myControllers', ['scrollOffset'] ); 

myControllers.controller('controller1',  [ '$scope', '$rootScope', '$routeParams',

function ( $scope, $rootScope, $routeParams ) {

    if ( $routeParams.scrollTo != 'undefined' ) {

        // get the target element
        var targetEl = document.getElementById ( $routeParams.scrollTo );

        // I want to fetch the scrollOffset attribute for targetEl here
    }
}]);
```

I'm new to Angular and can't figure this one out.  Part of the problem is that it looks to me like there are multiple way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you need something in multiple places, you're going to want to use dependency injection. For this example, probably the easiest thing to is to use the [value](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module) function on the module. Something like this:

```
myScroller.value("offsets", {});
```

Then you can inject the `offsets` object wherever needed. In the directive you can set values on it:

```
myScroller.directive('scrollOffset', function ( $rootScope, offsets ) {

    return function (scope, element, attr) {
        var offset = scope.$eval(attr.scrollOffset);
        offsets[element.id] = offset;                
    }   
});
```

Then in any controller you want, you can read values from it:

```
myControllers.controller('controller1',  [ '$scope', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', 'offsets',

function ( $scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, offsets ) {

    if ( $routeParams.scrollTo != 'undefined' ) {

        // get the target element
        var targetEl = document.getElementById ( $routeParams.scrollTo );
        // to make sure have value, use $watch
        $scope.$watch(function() {
            return offsets[$routeParams.scrollTo];
        }, function(newVal) {
            if (angular.isDefined(newVal)
            {
                 //do whatever you need to do with the value
            }
    }
}]);
```

If you don't want the object itself being exposed everywhere, you can encapsulate the functionality in a service with getter/setter type functionality, and then inject that where needed.

Comment: Thanks.  Your explanation and implementation make sense but when I test it, the controller is called before the directive and so the offsets array is empty.  Does that sound right?

Comment: I updated my answer to use a `$watch` so that you can make sure you have a value before doing anything.

Comment: Hi.  I've subsequently realised that accessing elements directly from a controller is bad practice and have re-written my code in a more Angular way.  However, thankyou for taking the time to answer my question and contributing to my Angular knowledge!